# What is proper way to embed a Vimeo video in an Ionic4 app?

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to embed a Vimeo video into my Ionic4 app.

I have done the obvious iframe approach but it does not handle fullscreen mode "properly". Wondering what the preferred method is for doing this.

With the iframe, the video plays fine in inline mode but it is very flaky flipping back and forth between fullscreen mode. Sometimes it does nothing trying to go back to inline. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it goes back to a different page in the app. When it flips between modes it usually restarts the video.

Hitting the devices back button seems to handle the video as expected; but not the fullscreen icon in the player.

I think the expected behavior is obvious. It should flip in/out of fullscreen mode when tapping the player's fullscreen icon and the video should remain at its current position and in its current play status (playing or paused).

I have come across https://github.com/videogular/videogular2 and not sure if this will do what I want; but does seem like overkill for something that should be simple.

I have also come across @vimeo/player but unclear that it supports fullscreen switching.